# Adding 2 python class objects together

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, object

I am having some problems adding two class objects together.
This is the code given to me, which will run MY file, the HyperLogLog and a sample text file:

```
import HyperLogLog
import sys

hlls = [HyperLogLog.HyperLogLog() for _ in range(5)]

with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as file:
for line in file:
    cleanLine = line.replace("\n", "")
    (cmd, set, value) = cleanLine.split(" ")[:3]
    # See if this was an add, count, or merge command
    if cmd == "A":
        hlls[int(set)].add(value)
    elif cmd == "C":
        estimate = hlls[int(set)].count()
        print("Estimate:", estimate, "Real count:", value)
    elif cmd == "M":
        (cmd, m1, m2, m3) = cleanLine.split(" ")
        hlls[int(m3)] = hlls[int(m1)] + hlls[int(m2)]
```

The bottom most line is to merge hlls(set m1) and hlls(set m2). hlls(set x) stores a single parameter M, which is my HyperLogLog vector. I need to make an **add** function to make the addition line above work. This I have done as follows:

```
class HyperLogLog:

def __init__(self):
    self.M = [0 for x in range(m)]   

##############
Code altering the self.M
##############

def __add__(self, other):
    Sum=other.M
    for i,value in enumerate(other.M):
        if value<self.M[i]:
            Sum[i]=self.M[i]
    self.M=Sum

    return self
```

This will return the correct value for the m3 set. But it will also alter the self.M value of set m1. How can I return something other than self, which will make hlls[int(m3)] and instance of the HyperLogLog class, with the merged self.M value?

If I just return the Sum function, hlls[int(m3)] is no longer an instance of the HyperLogLog class.

If I change self.M as I do, I alter the self.M value of hlls[int(m1)].

If I do something like:

```
    def __add__(self, other):
        Sum=other.M
        for i,value in enumerate(other.M):
            if value<self.M[i]:
                Sum[i]=self.M[i]

        self2=self
        self2.M=Sum


        return self2
```

The value of self.M of instance hlls[int(m1)] is still changed. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't create a new object instance. It just assigns another name to the same object.

```
self2=self
```

You should create a new `HyperLogLog` object in the `__add__` method.
Something like this:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    retval = HyperLogLog()
    retval.M = [max(a, b) for a, b in zip(self.M, other.M)]
    return retval
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
self2=self
```

Both `self` and `self2` point to the same object, so when one is changed the other one is changed as well. The easiest fix would be to create a new `HyperLogLog` object, so you would replace the line above with:

```
self2=HyperLogLog()
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sence. I also found, that I was altering he 'other' object along with the 'self'. What a nub I am :-)